# Python 2.4 inline if statements

Tags: python, django, dreamhost, python-2.5, python-2.4

I am setting up an existing django project on a dreamhost web server, so far I have got everything to work correctly. However I developed under python 2.5 and dreamhost by default uses python 2.4. The following line seems gives a syntax error because of the if keyword:

```
'parent': c.parent.pk if c.parent is not None else None
                       ^
```

Is it the case that this form of `if` statement was introduced in Python 2.5, if so is there an easy change that would make it compatible with Python 2.4?

Or, should I just change to Python 2.5. I have already installed python 2.5 to a directory under my home directory, and have succeeded in running the python interpreter under 2.5. If I wish to use Python 2.5 for everything, where can I set this?

Comment: I just found this page http://www.siafoo.net/article/52#selecting-values which explains that this was in fact introduced in Python 2.5, however my second questions still stands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this kind of inline if was [added with 2.5](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5/highlights/), released almost 4 years ago. You can update your Dreamhost version [like this](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Python#Installation)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html

```
(1 and [a] or [b])[0]
'parent': (c.parent is not None and [c.parent.pk] else [None])[0]
```

Comment: can be shortened to "c.parent or None" however that is slightly behavior changing as it is now doing a bool test, not a not None test